# How to deploy an IPv6 container with Docker Swarm Mode or Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ipv6, docker-swarm-mode

In the end I'd like to have a pure IPv6 network deployed via compose or swarm mode.  For now, I'd just like to have a single container deployed with IPv6 (only).  I am not currently interested in routing (just container to container connectivity).

My setup:

- OS: Centos 7
- dockerd --ipv6 --fixed-cidr-v6=2001:db8:1::/64 --iptables=true --ip-masq=true --mtu=1600 --experimental=true
- docker-engine-17.05.0.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
- Host has IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.  Forwarding is on for both (not that it matters for me).

I've tried what seems to be every combination (I'm only listing a couple)

**Self-contained Docker stack with container and network:**

```
version: '3'

networks:
  app_net:
    driver: overlay
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "true"
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      -
        subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
      -
        subnet: 2001:3984:3989::/64        

services:
  app:
    image: alpine
    command: sleep 600
    networks:
      app_net:
        ipv4_address: 0.0.0.0
        ipv6_address: 2001:3984:3989::10
```

**Result:** Only IPv4 address in container, 0.0.0.0 is ignored.

---

**Externally pre-created network**
(as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/39818953/1735931)

> docker network create  --driver overlay --ipv6
>   --subnet=2001:3984:3989::/64 --attachable ext_net

```
version: '3'

networks:
  ext_net:
    external:
      name: ext_net

services:
  app:
    image: alpine
    command: ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 ; sleep 600
    cap_add:
     - NET_ADMIN
    networks:
      ext_net:
        ipv4_address: 0.0.0.0
        ipv6_address: 2001:3984:3989::10
```

**Result:** Both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in container, but cap_add is ignored (not supported in Swarm Mode), and thus the ifconfig disable ipv4 attempt above does not work.

I don't currently have docker-compose installed, and will probably try that next, but **is there a way to run pure IPv6 containers in Docker Swarm Mode?**

Note: I am able to run and configure a few IPv6-only containers manually without swarm/compose:
(Create network as above or even just use the default bridge)

```
$ docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --rm -it alpine
$$ ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
$$ ping6 other-container-ipv6-address # WORKS!
```

or shorthand:

```
$ docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --rm -it alpine sh -c "/sbin/ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 ; sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hack it with **docker-compose** via severe ugliness.   If you're desperate, here it is.  (This method can never work for Swarm Mode due to privilege escalation).

**The Plan**

1. Grant containers rights to manage IP's
2. Remove IPv4 IP address from within each container on startup.
3. Use a volume to improvise a hosts file in place of DNS (DNS is IPv4-only in docker).

***Steps***

1. [Enable IPv6 in Docker daemon](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/ipv6/).
2. Create a docker-compose.yml file that creates an ipv6 network, a volume for shared files, and two containers
3. Run an entrypoint script in each container that performs the aforementioned steps.

***Files***

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# Note: enable_ipv6 does not work in version 3!
version: '2.1'

networks:
  app_net:
    enable_ipv6: true
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      -
        subnet: 172.16.238.0/24
      -
        subnet: 2001:3984:3989::/64

services:
  app1:
    build: ./server 
    hostname: server1
    command: blablabla # example of arg passing to ipv6.sh
    cap_add:
     - NET_ADMIN
    volumes:
     - ipv6stuff:/ipv6stuff
    networks:
      - app_net

  app2:
    build: ./server 
    hostname: server2
    command: SOMETHING # example of arg passing to ipv6.sh
    cap_add:
     - NET_ADMIN
    volumes:
     - ipv6stuff:/ipv6stuff
    networks:
      - app_net

volumes:
  ipv6stuff:
```

**server/Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest
ADD files /
RUN apk --update add bash  #simpler scripts
# Has to be an array for parameters to work via command: x in compose file, if needed
ENTRYPOINT ["/ipv6.sh"]
```

**server/files/ipv6.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Optionally conditional logic based on parameters here...
# (for example, conditionally leave ipv4 address alone in some containers)
#
# Remove ipv4
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0

IP6=$(ip addr show eth0 | grep inet6 | grep global | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d / -f 1)

echo "Host $HOSTNAME has ipv6 ip $IP6" 

# Store our entry in the shared volume
echo "$IP6   $HOSTNAME" > /ipv6stuff/hosts.$HOSTNAME

# Remove existing ipv4 line from /etc/hosts just to be thorough
# Docker does not allow removal of this file and thus simple sed -i isn't going to work.
cp /etc/hosts /tmp/1 ; sed -i "s/^.*\s$HOSTNAME//" /tmp/1 ; cat /tmp/1 > /etc/hosts

# Wait for all containers to start
sleep 2

# Put everyone's entries in our hosts file.
cat /ipv6stuff/hosts.* >> /etc/hosts

echo "My hosts file:"
cat /etc/hosts

# test connectivity (hardcoded)
ping6 -c 3 server1
ping6 -c 3 server2
```