# Deploying a docker private registry that supports IPv6

Tags: docker, ipv6

I am trying to deploy a private docker registry that supports IPv6. I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45577278/3413122) to define my IPv6 address.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry
      REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/registry.password
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY: /data
    volumes:
      - ./auth:/auth
      - ./data:/data
    networks:
      dock_net:
        ipv6_address: 2001:db8::10
networks:
  dock_net:
    enable_ipv6: true
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 2001:db8::/32
          gateway: 2001:db8::1
```

As far as I can tell it "works". A `docker inspect` shows the global IP address as the one I defined. I can ping the address, but if I issue `curl -u username:password http://[<ipv6 address>]:5000/v2/_catalog` on the host system (the one hosting the repository) it fails with no route to host.

Is there a step I missed during setup?

Comment: You have a bad address. `2001:197:2:1:12` is not a valid IPv6 address.

Comment: Sorry, that's just an example address, not the actual one I'm using. I'll update.

Comment: IANA has set aside a range, `2001:db8::/32`, to use for example addresses. If you are using example, rather than actual, addresses, then please use addresses in that range so that we know you mean example addresses.

Answer (score 0):

If need to be accessible from internet - you can put it behind cloudflare, and it will be accessible from both ipv6 and ipv4.